# C++ Default Values

Tags: c++

It pains me so bad to ask this question, I know the answer but I'm just completely blanking on it.

What my program is, is a simple program that displays damage. All I need is to be able to call my classes enemy and boss with the function attack. So basically `enemy.Attack()` or be able to call like this `enemy.Attack(30)` and have the output look different.

Here's what needs to happen:

`enemy.Attack()` Output: `10`

`enemy.Attack(30)` Output: `30`

Every time I attempt the empty bracket version, I get the error "function does not take 0 arguments"

## Enemy.h

```
class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy();
    void Attack();

private:
    int m_Damage;
};
```

## Enemy.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "enemy.h"

Enemy::Enemy() : m_Damage(10)
{}

void Enemy::Attack(int damage)
{
m_Damage = damage;
std::cout << "Damage: " << m_Damage << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `void Attack(int damage = 10)` in your declaration. The implementation stays as-is.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Please write that in an answer, so the question shows up as "answered". I think even that one line would suffice!

Comment: It really would, it fixed it entirely. I love you right now, and you also made me facepalm.

Comment: Googling the very title of this question yields the right answer in 0.14 seconds...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Provide default arguments in your class member declaration:

```
class Enemy
{
public:
    Enemy();
    void Attack(int damage = 10);

private:
    int m_Damage;
};
```

The remainder of your implementation can stay as-is (though I would default-construct `m_Damage` to zero myself, or not even use it, as I'm not sure you need it at this point).

Comment: An overload would work too. Of course the default argument is simpler.

Comment: Yup. And overloads don't confuse the hell out of people, when combined with polymorphism: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f53dbc2bce5580efbcdb35e41217ccbc-25dabfc2c190f5ef027f31d968947336